# Can we return a string or object in grapqhl while resolving?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

I wanted to check whether the user exists in database ... if user exists in the database then send

```
type user{
  name
  email
  password
  username
}
```

or if user doesn't exist in database then send a string which tells "user doesn't exists in database"

like.... if I am writing tyepDefs

```
type Query{
 show_data(username: String!): #if user exists then# ***user!*** or #if user doesnot exists then# ***String!***
```

How to make such type of resolvers and typeDefs ?

Comment: just `return null` if not found https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#return-values ... if you want error throw it https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#throwing-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new type to use in your query:

```
type UserPayload {
  state: String! # success or other value
  user: User # if state was not success this must be null
}
```

Then use that type directly by your query like this:

```
type Query{
 show_data(username: String!):UserPayload 
}
```

Comment: Show how to make play in playground using following Query ...

Comment: You can use your query normally ...
`show_data(username:"Username"){
  state
  user
}`

`state` is the string variable you want.

`user` is nullable it returns `null` or `User` type

Comment: if graphql is strongly typed then I think I shouldnot care about resolvers sending valid result .. if user doesn't exists in database then it would break and if had then It will sent valid response

Comment: How would I just return state, something like this return { state: 'state'}